# How to use the Common Lisp testing framework 'Prove'?

Tags: unit-testing, common-lisp

So I have this file named *test.lisp*. Here it is:

```
(in-package :cl-user)
(defpackage test
  (:use :cl
    :prove))
(in-package :test)

(defun square (x) (* x x))

(plan 3)

(ok (not (find 4 '(1 2 3))))
(is 4 4)
(is (square 3) 9)

(finalize)
```

When I load this file ie

```
(load "test.lisp")
```

the 3 tests get completed - it is successful; but when I try to call the function `square` I get an error saying that `square` is undefined.

Why is this happening?

I would like to know how to use `Prove` given a src file.

Thanks

Comment: how about showing the actual input and errror?

Comment: If `(test::square 6)` works, go to http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/programming-in-the-large-packages-and-symbols.html

Comment: Note that [Rove](https://github.com/fukamachi/rove) is the author's official continuation to Prove.

Answer (score 2):

As coredump‘s comment suggest your problem might be unrelated to `prove` and you should get used to the logic of CL packages.

If you need more information about *testing* there are very good examples in the CL [cookbook](https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/testing.html).

Answer (score 1):

Your package definition should `export` the names in the package which you want access to from outside the package:

```
(in-package :cl-user)

(defpackage test
  (:use :cl
    :prove)
  (:documentation "My new test package.")
  (:export :square)) ;; add more functions/variables if you want to make them
                     ;; available for user who imports this package 'test'

(in-package :test)
```

Now, after `(load "test.lisp")` the `:export`ed names are available outside the package. Or do how @coredump suggested - without `:export`ing -:

access the non-`:export`ed names inside the package by `test::square` (`<packagename>::<func/var-name>`).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by exporting the `square` procedure; like so:

```
(in-package :cl-user)
(defpackage test
  (:use :cl
    :prove)
  (:export :square)) ; like so - exporting `square`
(in-package :test)

(defun square (x) (* x x))

(plan 3)

(ok (not (find 4 '(1 2 3))))
(is 4 4)
(is (square 3) 9)

(finalize)
```

I then loaded the file and evaluated:

```
(use-package :test)
```

I was able to call `square`. Woohoo!

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim similar answer but not exactly the same. i figured it out before looking at your answer; this is why I answered my question. A slightly different answer.